# ListView or TableLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-tablelayout

I have a confusion as to what i should use for this case in particular
I want to load some data from a local database in to a list ,there will be one more column which will have a checkbox which will dynamically recieve input at runtime

After this all the data will be loaded it another database table

so the question is for such a list
Should i use a ListView or TableLayout?
i understand that if i need to make use of a ListView i will have to make a custom list 
but then again i am not quite sure as to how to handle the data recieved and push into another table
please explain
also any link as to how i should go about it is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly, definitely go with a listview.

listview is just a view that takes data from adapter which source is a database in your case, and then shows it using simple (each item from adapter represented as single textview) or complex (each item from database prestend as textview + checkbox + whatnot) view.

it's true that to use a listview you have to write some code (prepare adapter, maybe a loader to get's data from db into that adapter) but it's very basic and, what's important, very commonly used on android platform.

i bet that to better answer your question, you could show us screen of your app, view you have to create.